# Adding parameters to cpdef func definition in derived cython class

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to change the method signature of a cpdef method in a derived class but keep getting errors.

In *.pxd:

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint64_t

cdef struct _ft_device_list_info_node_os:
        uint64_t ftHandle
ctypedef _ft_device_list_info_node_os FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE_OS

cdef class BaseClass(object):
    cpdef object do_something(BaseClass self)

cdef class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    cdef FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE_OS cheese
```

In *.pyx:

```
cdef class BaseClass(object):

    cpdef object do_something(BaseClass self):
        pass

cdef class DerivedClass(BaseClass):

    cpdef object do_something(DerivedClass self, int val=10):
        cdef FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE_OS node
        self.cheese = node
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
cythoning test.pyx to pybarst\test.cpp

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef class DerivedClass(BaseClass):

    cpdef object do_something(DerivedClass self, int val=10):
        cdef FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE_OS node
        self.cheese = node
                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:10:26: Cannot convert 'FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE_OS' to Python object
```

This error doesn't seem to happen if the struct is defined with only ints or simpler data types, i.e. if I do `int ftHandle` the error does not occur.

It seems that it gets confused in the derived class's `do_something` method, where it thinks that it is the base class and therefore cannot find `cheese`.

Is there maybe a proper way of adding parameters in a derived class.

Comment: Are you sure that Cython is properly reading your .pxd file ? Where is ` FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE_OS` defined ? With a proper .h and .pxd defining it is works for me (that is I got `bla.pyx:10:26: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment`)

Comment: Yes, the struct needs to have certain types for this to happen. It does happen even if you define it in cython directly. See my edit.

Comment: And before you ask, I do `from libc.stdint cimport uint64_t` :)

Comment: I think i'll need a SSCCE. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. Yes, before they were with other code, but the error still occurs when I move it into their own files. I edited the post to reflect that, but I didn't add any new info.

Comment: Ah, I'm using cython 0.20 (returned by cython -V). Also, in my setup file I pass `language="c++"` to `Extension`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug that they fixed with [this](https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/0ebc91f2c644fe4b2929fd1cc6fbe1f65a45243a). See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cython-users/ClG1gFgfCRY).